# Is there a way to establish what version a Windows 7 product key is?

Tags: windows-7, license, license-key, product-key

I have a Windows 7 product key that I foolishly did not label.  Rather than downloading and creating disks for however many different ISOs exist (Basic, Pro, Ultimate, 32-bit/64-bit, upgrade, full version) and testing each one until one works, is there a way I can discover what the key is for specifically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [Windows 7 Product Key Checker](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Info/Windows-7-Product-Key-Checker.shtml) or [Microsoft PIDX Check](http://www.mydigitallife.info/microsoft-pidx-product-key-checker-for-windows-7-free-download/) (note: not actually a Microsoft product).

Use them at your own risk, though. Since at least PIDX Check seems to have originally been written for use with activation cracks, my first concern would be that it might try to "leak" the product key to some third party, so you may want to run it in some sort of sandbox and make sure it cannot access the internet.

I also found [an open-source product key checker](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/10858-Open-source-Windows-7-product-key-checker); if you're so inclined, you can review the source code to ensure it doesn't do anything unexpected with the product key, and then compile it to an executable yourself.

Answer (score -1):

> [The Ultimate PID Checker](http://en.janek2012.eu/ultimate-pid-checker/) is an application that allows you to
>   calculate Windows 8 / Server 2012, Windows 7 / Server 2008 R2, Windows
>   Vista / Server 2008, Windows XP / Server 2003 and MS Office 2010
>   Product IDs from given keys. It can read the keys from a text file and
>   allows you to extend its functionality by loading custom pkeyconfig
>   (from future Windows versions for example).

Comment: FYI, the link no longer works.