# How do I check if a Windows key is genuine without activating it?

Tags: windows, product-key, windows-genuine-advantage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to establish what version a Windows 7 product key is?](https://superuser.com/questions/430407/is-there-a-way-to-establish-what-version-a-windows-7-product-key-is)

I need a way to test if a Windows 7 key is genuine, and for what version it is so.  I would like to do this *without* activating it.

What would be ideal is an application where I can input a key, and have it tell me what Windows it is for (7, Vista, XP, etc.) and the type (Home Premium, Professional, Ultimate, etc.)

Comment: None of the tools in that thread are available anymore.

Comment: And yes I do mean genuine, I want to know if it will activate without any issues.

Comment: Actually, correction again, the first tool works.

Comment: The first link (to Softpedia) still works. The others seem down, yes. There's also this online checker: http://d-fault.nl/PIDCheck.aspx, though whether or not you trust it is your call.